# Change color of selected page number (pagination)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple React component with a table displaying 10 rows of data per page. The implementation of the pagination works as intended, but I want to be able to highlight the selected page.

In my constructor I have an initial state "active: null", which I then modify in a handleClick function.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  currentPage: 1,
  eventsPerPage: 10,
  active: null,
};
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(index) {
this.setState({ currentPage: Number(index.target.id) });
if (this.state.active === index) {
  this.setState({ active: null });
} else {
  this.setState({ active: index });
}
}
```

And a function for setting the font-weight to bold.

```
myStyle(index) {
if (this.state.active === index) {
  return 'bold';
}
return '';
}
```

Here is what I render.

```
const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map((number, index) => (

  <p
    style={{ fontWeight: this.myStyle(index) }}
    key={number}
    id={number}
    onClick={index => this.handleClick(index)}
  >
    {number}
  </p>
));

return (
        <div id="page-numbers">
          {renderPageNumbers}
        </div>
);
```

FYI: It's not the complete code.

I am not quite sure where I go wrong, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: do you get bold text for selected page?

Comment: can you please upload the two screen shots of (1) screen shot of what you have and (2) screen shot of what you want

Comment: Nothing happens. I want the selected page number to be bold, the unselected pagenumbers remain normal.

Comment: OK. Now I understand your question.

Comment: That’s good. Would you happen to know how I should proceed to accomplish this?

Comment: is `myStyle` being called? log the arguments to see what's wrong

Comment: Why are you setting `this.setState({ active: null });` in the onClick handler? Shouldn't a click always set the active page? It looks like it might be unsetting the active page if the active page is already selected? Why would you want that either?

Comment: `onClick={index => this.handleClick(index)}` is definitely your problem as well..... you're overwriting your `index` parameter from the map function

Answer (score 0):

`pageNumbers.map((number, index) =>` index is zero based and am sure number starts from 1 so when `index === 0 and number === 1`, you would have `this.myStyle(0)` but 
`this.handleClick(0)` will not work because you first `#id === 1` not `0`

why not just use number for your functions and remove index to safe confusion

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind the context of the class to `myStyle` function in order to use `this` inside it.

So, in your `constructor` you should add it like this:
(see the last line)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentPage: 1,
        eventsPerPage: 10,
        active: null,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.myStyle = this.myStyle.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Oh I confused it with `handleClick`. Apologies. Unfortunately I can't undo my vote unless the answer is edited :(